# Azure Notification Hub: installation id and how to handle uninstall of the app

Tags: ios, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I'm using Azure Notification Hub for sending push notification.

I'm generating the guid for the installation and using the Installation Id with the notification hub.

Everything works ok.

The problem is when i uninstall the application! In IOS, when i uninstall the application, the guid is removed and when i reinstall the app, a new id is created so in the notification hub i see two record

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backend then you should be using the device token in:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

}
```

**Correction** in regards to device IDs as the documentation states:

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another
>   app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value
>   changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the
>   device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them.

Basically there is no way to uniquely identify a device after the user uninstalled the app(s).

Check out this article for more details: 
http://nshipster.com/uuid-udid-unique-identifier/

Answer (score 0):

When you try to send a notification to the two device entries, only the new registration will be acknowledged by the device, so the device will only receive one notification.

For the old registration, Apple will send the Notification Hub feedback that the registration is no longer valid, and the Notification Hub will remove the registration from its database.

So you don't need to do anything, really.